# How to make GeoJSON data uneditable through leaflet.pm

Tags: javascript, leaflet, draw, leaflet-geoman

I have a geojson file and I get it with ajax. but I want to prevent the editing of the geometries I load during startup. Only the ones that are added with leaflet.pm should be editable.
How can i do it ?

[leaflet.pm](https://github.com/codeofsumit/leaflet.pm)

I'm using geojson coordinate json. these drawings are added to the map when the page loads.

{pmIgnored: true} after trying to delete delete mode when I click on one of the static drawings I added from geojson deletes all of them. How can I prevent it?

```
var geojsonData;
// addded geojson ajax
$.getJSON("geo.json", {
  async: false,
}, function (data) {
  geojsonData = L.geoJson(data, {
    pmIgnore: true, // ignore static shaped edited
    style: {
      weight: 20
    },
  }).addTo(map);
});
```

what I want to do is not to delete static coordinates in any way when deletion mode is turned on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm Sumit, the maintainer of leaflet.pm

I think [there was a bug](https://github.com/codeofsumit/leaflet.pm/issues/401) regarding ignoring of layers through `pmIgnore: true` in the global removal mode.
It should be fixed [in this release](https://github.com/codeofsumit/leaflet.pm/releases/tag/2.0.3). Please test version 2.0.3 or newer and let me know if it works.

If you still encounter problems, feel free to [report it here](https://github.com/codeofsumit/leaflet.pm/issues) with a JSFiddle showing the problem and I'm happy to help/fix it.

Comment: I did not encounter any problems in version 2.0.3. It works very well.

Answer (score 3):

Apply the `pmIgnore` option not to the group, but to each individual leaflet layer. Do this with the `style` and `pointToLayer` options of `L.GeoJSON`, e.g.:

```
  geojsonData = L.geoJson(data, {
    style: {
      pmIgnore: true,
      weight: 20
    },
  })
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly.  I was trying to figure out how to add it to an individual layer and didn't realize I could do it this way.